# How to ask my classmates to stop talking to me in class?

Tags: friends, india

I know that a similar question has been asked before, but the culture and location is different, and so is the context, to some extent.

My classmates keep talking to me in class, and I have a strong feeling that my grades are going down because of that. I often join in on their conversation, but regret it later. I need to tell them that I don't want to talk when the teacher is teaching us, but I don't want them to feel bad or that I've left their peer group in any way. What would be the best way to do so?

Link to similar question: [How to stop colleague from talking so much when subtle hints are not working?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/how-to-stop-colleague-from-talking-so-much-when-subtle-hints-are-not-working/)

Comment: Does your friend also care about their grades or are they mostly there to socialize?

Comment: @EricaGrant Mostly, they chill out and socialize...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I'm from India as well. When I went through this in school, I went to my teachers and told them to move me from my desk to a different desk so I am far away from the friends.

Tell your teachers clearly that you are not able to pay attention and you don't want to lose your friendship with these classmates, but you'd rather not sit near them. If you have even a slightly decent rapport with your teachers, they'd be happy to hear that.

My teachers, since I told them this, came into the classroom and the first thing they do, call my name out, and ask me to sit in the front desk. Away from all the people that are my friends. No one knew why I was being asked to do that and no one assumed it was because I went up to the teacher and told her to do so.

This also earns you a lot of beautiful brownie points from your teachers for showing that you actually care about the class and that you want to pay attention and get good grades.

This, in my opinion, is the cleanest way to rip this bandage off without hurting anyone.

I don't know how typical it is for the teacher to move students around in the classroom in other countries. But I do know that is very common in India.

Comment: I upvotes this *chaala* clever and elegant solution which also earns bonus brownie points, @Crazy Cucumber! (For non-Indian members: in Telugu language the very commonly used word *chaala* = very or [a lot](http://www.shabdkosh.com/te/translate/chaala/chaala-meaning-in-Telugu-English)) Now, later telling your friends in a aggrieved tone that "why she want to move me away from you to the front bench like that, the busybody!" might well be [gilding the lily...](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gild-the-lily)